# Redefine smart key mappings in vim's Latex-suite plugin

Tags: vim, keyboard, vim-latex

When using the Latex-suite plugin in vim, typing `...` expands to either  `\ldots` or `\cdots` (see section [3.9 Smart Key Mappings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#smart-keys) of the latex-suite manual).
I am using a lot the *amsmath* package that provides `\dots`, and I'd like to make `...` expand to just `\dots`.

I tried putting

```
:call IMAP('...', '\dots','tex')
```

in `$VIM/after/ftplugin/tex_macros.vim` but it does nothing.

How can I make `...` expand to `\dots`?

Moreover, is there any way to do the above *only* if the *amsmath* package is detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why what you tried didn't work (maybe you have to disable Smart Dots), disabling Smart Dots with `let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot=0` in my vimrc and appending `call IMAP('...', '\dots','tex')` to `ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim` worked for me, but that's not what I would recommend. **I would recommend using `::`, which expands to `\dots` by default**, as far as I know.

Comment: I had no idea about the :: shortcut, I'm going with that, thanks!

Comment: I'm not even sure it's documented. I found it by accident.